# Получение id checkbox после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery

С одной задачкой появилась небольшая проблема. Нужно что бы после выделения `checkbox` и нажатия кнопки выводилось `id` этого `checkbox`, но у меня чего то не выходит, помогите пожалуйста.

```js
$('#button_').click(function() {
            if ($(':checkbox').is(':checked')) {
            var id = this.id;//здесь должно сохранятся id checkbox
            alert(id);
          }
          else {
            alert('Перед нажатием на кнопку выделите checkbox!');
          }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="3">
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="button_" value="Tap me!">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#button_').click(function() {
  var msg = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').attr('id') || 'Перед нажатием на кнопку выделите checkbox!';
  alert(msg);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="2">
<input type="checkbox" id="3">
<br>
<input type="button" id="button_" value="Tap me!">
```

Answer (score 2):

для этой задачи совсем не нужно подключать громоздкий jquery

```js
document.getElementById('button_').onclick=function(){

  var chkd=document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
  for (var i=0; i<chkd.length; i++){
   console.log(chkd[i].getAttribute("id"));
                                    }
  chkd.length==0 ? console.log('Перед нажатием на кнопку выделите checkbox!'):0;
        
}
```

```html
    <input type="checkbox" id="1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="3">
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="button_" value="Tap me!">
```